# Add computed COUNT column from one view to another view

Tags: mysql, join, count, formula, average

I have a view referencing a vendors table with vendor contact information and a vendor_ratings table to display a an average rating for each vendor. The view works when pulling up vendor information and rating averages, but I have another view that tells me the number of times each vendor has been rated. This view works fine but I can not get it to work in my join view.

This is the code for the view that works with vendor information & average ratings:

```
SELECT
vendors.ID,
vendors.Vendor,
ROUND(((AVG(`Cost_Rating`) + AVG(`Documentation_Rating`) + AVG(`Safety_Rating`) + AVG(`Equipment_Rating`) + AVG(`Performance_Rating`) + AVG(`Promptness_Rating`) + AVG(`Communication_Rating`))/7.0), 2) AS `Overall Rating`,
vendors.`Phone #`,
vendors.`Fax #`,
vendors.Website,
vendors.`Physical Address`,
vendors.`P.O. Box`,
vendors.City,
vendors.`State`,
vendors.Zip,
vendors.`Region Serving`,
vendors.Note,
vendors.OnVendorList,
vendors.`Search Words`,
ROUND(AVG(`Communication_Rating`), 2) AS `Average Communication Rating`,
ROUND(AVG(`Promptness_Rating`), 2) AS `Average Promptness Rating`,
ROUND(AVG(`Performance_Rating`), 2) AS `Average Performance Rating`,
ROUND(AVG(`Equipment_Rating`), 2) AS `Average Equipment Rating`,
ROUND(AVG(`Safety_Rating`), 2) AS `Average Safety Rating`,
ROUND(AVG(`Documentation_Rating`), 2) AS `Average Documentation Rating`,
ROUND(AVG(`Cost_Rating`), 2) AS `Average Cost Rating`

FROM vendors
LEFT OUTER JOIN `vendor ratings` ON vendors.Vendor = `vendor ratings`.Vendor
GROUP BY vendor
```

This is the code to my other view which shows the number of times each vendor has been rated:

```
SELECT
Vendor,
COUNT(Vendor) AS `COUNT(Vendor)`
FROM `vendor ratings`
GROUP BY Vendor
ORDER BY Vendor
```

I tried adding the line: COUNT(vendor As `COUNT(Vendor)`, into the code that is already working for everything else but with no success. What am I doing wrong? I just the results to look like this...

Vendor, Ave Rating, # of Times Rated, Phone #, etc......

Comment: `SELECT * .. FROM GROUP BY vendor` is not valid ANSI SQL and is basically is wrong unless MySQL could used functional dependency do get the data correct per group which i doubt in this case.

Comment: You should be able to use `COUNT(vendor_ratings.Vendor)`

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Do the summarization before you join (i.e. use a subquery or "derived table")

```
SELECT
      v.*
    , vr.*
FROM
FROM vendors v
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT
            vendors.Vendor
          , COUNT(*)                                    AS `COUNT(Vendor) `
          , ROUND(((AVG(`Cost_Rating`) 
            + AVG(`Documentation_Rating`) 
            + AVG(`Safety_Rating`) 
            + AVG(`Equipment_Rating`) 
            + AVG(`Performance_Rating`) 
            + AVG(`Promptness_Rating`) 
            + AVG(`Communication_Rating`)) / 7.0), 2)   AS `Overall Rating`
          , ROUND(AVG(`Communication_Rating`), 2)       AS `Average Communication Rating`
          , ROUND(AVG(`Promptness_Rating`), 2)          AS `Average Promptness Rating`
          , ROUND(AVG(`Performance_Rating`), 2)         AS `Average Performance Rating`
          , ROUND(AVG(`Equipment_Rating`), 2)           AS `Average Equipment Rating`
          , ROUND(AVG(`Safety_Rating`), 2)              AS `Average Safety Rating`
          , ROUND(AVG(`Documentation_Rating`), 2)       AS `Average Documentation Rating`
          , ROUND(AVG(`Cost_Rating`), 2)                AS `Average Cost Rating`
     FROM `vendor ratings`
     GROUP BY vendors.Vendor
     ) vr ON v.Vendor = vr.Vendor
```

Please note that MySQL has a very unfortunate way of allowing `group by` clauses to have only a few of the non-aggregating columns that exist in the select clause. This is NOT good practice and it can lead to "unexpected results". Slowly MySQL is improving this area but you should be alert to this problem [here's a start](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-5-7-only_full_group_by-improved-recognizing-functional-dependencies-enabled-by-default/). Research **only_full_group_by**

- please note I do NOT recommend using `select v.*, vr.*` in your final code, list out the columns you need, I have done this only to focus attention on the subquery
- but I DO recommend that you prefix ALL columns after the join by the relevant table prefix.